# how can I handle properly the behavior of camera in my Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation, avcapturesession

In my `swift` app I'm allowing users to take photos.

For that purpose I've decided to use `CameraManager` from here: https://github.com/imaginary-cloud/CameraManager

When user opens my app, he sees a button - when he presses it, the camera view appears and he can take a photo. He also can dismiss the camera view and later on, at some point, press the button one more time to open camera view again.

If I understand it correctly from the plugin docs, I need to add a camera view to my view during first usage, then - in case of dismiss - invoke `stopCaptureSession()`, and during every next usage call `resumeCaptureSession()`.

Currently in my `swift` code I have three methods:

```
let cameraManager = CameraManager()

fileprivate func addCameraToView()
{
    cameraManager.addPreviewLayerToView(cameraView, newCameraOutputMode: CameraOutputMode.stillImage)
}

fileprivate func stopCaptureSession() {
    cameraManager.stopCaptureSession()
}

fileprivate func resumeCaptreSession() {
    cameraManager.resumeCaptureSession()
}
```

The `IBAction` for the button has the following code:

```
let currentCameraState = cameraManager.currentCameraStatus()
    if currentCameraState == .notDetermined {
        cameraManager.askUserForCameraPermission({ permissionGranted in
            if permissionGranted {
                self.resumeCaptreSession()
            }
        })
    } else if (currentCameraState == .ready) {
        self.resumeCaptreSession()
    } else {
        print("we do not have access to camera")
    }
```

and in the `IBAction` for the dismiss button I had:

```
    print("cancelling camera")
    stopCaptureSession()
```

To make it work properly, I need to call `addCameraToView()` somewhere earlier - until now I was adding it in `viewDidLoad`, but I realized that I cannot do that because while doing so - the camera stays active until user presses the `dismiss` button.

So I thought about changing my code in `IBAction` for the camera button and add a camera from there. However, I have to add it only in case it wasn't add before - in the other case I need to call `resumeCaptureSession()`.

The problem is that in `CameraManager` the function responsible for adding camera to the view is declared like this:

```
open func addPreviewLayerToView(_ view: UIView, newCameraOutputMode: CameraOutputMode) -> CameraState {
    return addLayerPreviewToView(view, newCameraOutputMode: newCameraOutputMode, completion: nil)
}

open func addLayerPreviewToView(_ view: UIView, newCameraOutputMode: CameraOutputMode, completion: ((Void) -> Void)?) -> CameraState {
    if _canLoadCamera() {
        if let _ = embeddingView {
            if let validPreviewLayer = previewLayer {
                validPreviewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }
        if cameraIsSetup {
            _addPreviewLayerToView(view)
            cameraOutputMode = newCameraOutputMode
            if let validCompletion = completion {
                validCompletion()
            }
        } else {
            _setupCamera({ Void -> Void in
                self._addPreviewLayerToView(view)
                self.cameraOutputMode = newCameraOutputMode
                if let validCompletion = completion {
                    validCompletion()
                }
            })
        }
    }
    return _checkIfCameraIsAvailable()
}
```

and `resumeCaptureSession()` is defined like this:

```
open func resumeCaptureSession() {
    if let validCaptureSession = captureSession {
        if !validCaptureSession.isRunning && cameraIsSetup {
            validCaptureSession.startRunning()
            _startFollowingDeviceOrientation()
        }
    } else {
        if _canLoadCamera() {
            if cameraIsSetup {
                stopAndRemoveCaptureSession()
            }
            _setupCamera({Void -> Void in
                if let validEmbeddingView = self.embeddingView {
                    self._addPreviewLayerToView(validEmbeddingView)
                }
                self._startFollowingDeviceOrientation()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is - when user opens camera view, how can I check if camera was added to the view before, and if it was added - call `resumeCaptureSession()`, otherwise do not call it and just leave it with calling `addCameraToView`?

Comment: Just check to see if camera object is nil

Comment: @WillBoland when exactly and how should I check it? I thought that it will never be nil since I'm writing 'let cameraManager = CameraManager()'